# Como verificar se um id existe na página

Tags: php, javascript, html, json

fiz um JavaScript que gera vários cards cada um deles com um id, para evitar criar cards repetidos eu coloquei um if antes da geração dos cards para verificar se ele já existe, porém não deu certo:

```
$(document).on('click', '#carregarMaisFiltro',function(){ 
    var init = (jQuery('.anunciosJsonFiltro').length);
    var combo = document.getElementById("busca_anuncio_categoria");
    var categoria = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].value; 
    var comboEstado = document.getElementById("busca_anuncio_estado");
    var estado = comboEstado.options[comboEstado.selectedIndex].value; 
    carregar(init, 3, categoria, estado,'Chamadas/listarAnuncios.php')
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#btn_filtrarAnuncio',function(evento){ 
    var combo = document.getElementById("busca_anuncio_categoria");
    var categoria = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].value; 
    var comboEstado = document.getElementById("busca_anuncio_estado");
    var estado = comboEstado.options[comboEstado.selectedIndex].value; 
    evento.preventDefault();
    carregar(0, 3, categoria, estado, 'Chamadas/listarAnuncios.php');
    document.getElementById('cardAnuncios').innerHTML = "";
  });

  function carregar(init, max, categoria, estado, url){
  var dados = { init : init, max : max, categoria : categoria, estado : estado };
  if(init >= 3)
  {
      $('#img_loadBuscarAnuncio').fadeIn('slow');
      $('#cardContainer').css("opacity", 0.4);
  }
  $.post(url, dados, function (data) {
      $("#carregarMaisFiltro").last().remove();

      for(i = 0; i < data.dados.length; i++){
          var img = data.dados[i].img ? data.dados[i].img : "../anuncio-padrao.png";
          if (document.getElementById('"'+data.dados[i].cd_anuncio+'"') == null || document.getElementById('"'+data.dados[i].cd_anuncio+'"') == undefined){


      $("#cardAnuncios").append('<div class="anunciosJsonFiltro" id="'+data.dados[i].cd_anuncio+'" value="'+data.dados[i].cd_anuncio+'">'
          +'<a style="display: block; color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);" href="#">'
               +'<div style="box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12); overflow: hidden; margin-bottom: 6px;">'  
                   +'<div class="col s4 m4" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">'
                      +'<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">'
                          +'<div style="display: inline-block; position: relative; right: -50%;">'
                               +'<img src="img/anuncios/'+img+'" alt="user background" style="height: 150px; width: auto; position: relative; left: -50%; vertical-align: bottom;">'
                           +'</div>'
                       +'</div>'
                   +'</div>'
                   +'<div class="col s8 m8 truncate-text" style="padding-left: 14px; padding-top: 8px; height: 150px;">'
                           +'<span class="grey-text text-darken-4" style="font-size: 20px;">'+data.dados[i].nm_titulo+'</span>'
                          +'<br>'
                          +'<span class="grey-text">Anúncio criado por: '+data.dadosComplementares[i].nm_usuario+' em '+moment(data.dados[i].dt_criacao).format("DD/MM/YYYY")+'</span>'
                          +'<div class="star-result" style="margin-bottom: -10px;">'
                               +'<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">'
                               +'<style>'
                                   +'.checked {'
                                       +'color: orange;'
                                  +'}'
                             +'</style>'
                              +'<span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>'
                               +'<span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>'
                               +'<span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>'
                               +'<span class="fa fa-star"></span>'
                               +'<span class="fa fa-star"></span>'
                           +'</div>'
                           +'<br>'
                           +'<i class="mdi-image-navigate-next cyan-text text-darken-2"></i>'
                           +'<span class="cyan-text text-darken-2">'+data.dadosComplementares[i].categoria+'</span>'
                           +'<br>'
                           +'<i class="mdi-communication-location-on cyan-text text-darken-2"></i>'
                          +'<span class="cyan-text text-darken-2">'+data.dadosComplementares[i].bairro+', '+data.dadosComplementares[i].municipio+' - '+data.dadosComplementares[i].estado+'</span>'
                   +'</div>'
               +'</div>'
           +'</a>'
           +'</div>');
      }
    }

      if(data.dados.length > 0)
      {
          $("#cardAnuncios").append('<button id="carregarMaisFiltro" class="btn right" style="background-color: #0097a7;" type="submit" name="action"><center>Carregar mais</center></button>');
      }; 
      var conta = $(".anunciosJsonFiltro").length;

      if(conta == data.totalAnuncios+init) {
          // deveria parar aqui  < ------
          $("#carregarMaisFiltro").last().remove();
          $('#img_loadBuscarAnuncio').fadeOut('slow');
          $('#cardContainer').css("opacity", 1.0);
          $("#carregarMaisFiltro").hide();
      }
  }, "json");
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua ideia está certa, mas a implementação está um pouco estranha.

```
document.getElementById('"'+data.dados[i].cd_anuncio+'"')
```

Por que você está concatenando aspas duplas com o id? Aspas servem para declarar uma string, elas não faz parte da query em sí, por isso sua query não está funcionando, um simples `document.getElementById(data.dados[i].cd_anuncio)` bastaria. Além disso não há a necessidade de comparar o resultado com `undefined`, se a query não encontrar o elemento, ela retornará `null`.

Comment: realmente, falta de atenção minha vlw

Comment: Na verdade deveria ser `if(!document.getElementById(data.dados[i].cd_anuncio)){` porque ele deseja saber se a `id` não existe.